# Add exception to shouldOverrideUrlLoading in Android Studio?

Tags: android, webview

I've been trying to figure this out but without any luck so far... So basically, I've got my standard webview app where I call my shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Here is the piece of code

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

But I'd like to add an exception to this. The exception should be: if the url does not contain "scheppersonline", do not open in the webview but in the standard browser app. I tried achieving this by doing:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("scheppersonline.be")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I'm just starting out with coding, so any help would be appreciated! :)

logcat:

```
01-27 13:51:01.406 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28229
01-27 13:51:01.422 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null", source:  (1)
01-27 13:51:02.238 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28229
01-27 13:51:03.894 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28229
01-27 13:51:04.064 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(129)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", source: http://scheppersonline.be/wp-content/themes/accesspress-staple/js/main-menu.js?ver=1.0 (129)
01-27 13:51:08.917 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:571] focusedNodeChanged
01-27 13:51:08.935 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:213] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0], flags [0], show [true]
01-27 13:51:08.936 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen D/cr_Ime: [AdapterInputConnection.java:178] updateState [] [0 0] [-1 -1] [true]
01-27 13:51:09.842 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28229
01-27 13:51:25.195 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:213] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0], flags [0], show [true]
01-27 13:51:25.195 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen D/cr_Ime: [AdapterInputConnection.java:178] updateState [] [0 0] [-1 -1] [true]
01-27 13:51:26.781 28229-28229/com.vanbilsen.bram.scheppersmechelen W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28229
```

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't seem to work" means. In your code, if the URL contains your string, the URL will be shown in the `WebView`; otherwise, the URL will be shown in the user's default Web browser.

Comment: The thing that doesn't work is the open in standard browser if the url does not contain "scheppersonline" condition. Everything just opens in my webView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` returns is True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise it is false

To clarify... When you return false you are NOT saying don't load the url. You are actually saying ok let the WebView take care of loading the url.

What you really want is something like:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if (!url.contains("scheppersonline.be")) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oké, thank you for that! But then the follow up question, how can I achieve my goal to not load in the webview?

Comment: Hi, that code didn't work for me. It loads the url's with "scheppersonline.be" but it doesn't load for example "google.com" at all. So it doesn't open the standard browser.

Comment: Ahh sorry I miss-read your question. Thought you only wanted the `WebView` to open urls containing "scheppersonline.be".

Comment: In Android, if you want some other app (for example the default browser) to do do some thing, you let it know via an Intent. See my new edit.